# Fiware Orion + Cosmos: Subscription failed - Timeout was reached trying to notify a PC that belongs to the same network

Tags: docker, scala, apache-spark, fiware-orion, fiware-cosmos

I have a scenario on a Citrix Xenserver server with 3 virtual machines (VM) Centos7 on the same network (10.0.1.0/24). Each VM are responsible to give a prediction done with Apache Spark on Scala (Logistic Regression). I use Orion Context broker (CB) on Docker to create subscriptions that will be triggered to ask predictions. The CB it is located only in 10.0.1.4 VM and I made some ports available to access from the other machines.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
 mongo:
   image: mongo:4.4
   command: --nojournal
 orion:
   image: fiware/orion
   links:
     - mongo
   ports:
     - "1026:1026"
     - "1027:1027"
     - "1028:1028"
     - "9090:9090"
     
   command: -dbhost mongo -corsOrigin __ALL
```

For example, to access CB from 10.0.1.2 VM I use 10.0.1.4:1028/..... and so on.

This is the subscription I'm facing problems (and maybe the other related to 10.0.1.3 VM must have the same problem too)

```
 curl -v localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions -s -S -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- <<EOF
{
  "description": "Suscripcion de anemia para monitorear al Paciente",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "Paciente1",
        "type": "Paciente"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": ["calculateAnaemia"]
    },
    "expression":{
        "q":"calculateAnaemia:1"
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://10.0.1.2:9002/notify"
    },
    
    "attrs": ["gender","age","hemoglobin","mch","mchc","mcv"]
    
  },
  "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
  "throttling": 10
  
}
EOF
```

I have a code on the 10.0.1.2 VM that is listening about changes related to this subscription on port 9002 with Fiware Cosmos:

> For *eventStream* variable on 10.0.1.4 VM got port 9004 and for 10.0.1.3 VM it is 9003 port

> For *conf* variable I set "spark.driver.host" on 10.0.1.4 VM with 10.0.1.4 IP and for 10.0.1.3 VM to 10.0.1.3 IP

```
import esqMensajeria.ActorSysMensajeria.ActoresEsquema
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.fiware.cosmos.orion.spark.connector._

object Main extends App{
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("AnaemiaPrediction").set("spark.driver.host", "10.0.1.2")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))
    // Create Orion Source. Receive notifications on port 9002
    val eventStream = ssc.receiverStream(new OrionReceiver(9002))
    // Esquema de mensajeria
    val actorSysMsj = new ActoresEsquema ()
    println("Esperando cambios para obtener información...")
    // Process event stream
    val processedDataStream = eventStream
      .flatMap(event => event.entities)
      .map(entity => {
        val gender: Int = entity.attrs("gender").value.asInstanceOf[Number].intValue()
        val age: Int = entity.attrs("age").value.asInstanceOf[Number].intValue()
        val hemoglobin: Double = entity.attrs("hemoglobin").value.asInstanceOf[Double].doubleValue()
        val mch: Double = entity.attrs("mch").value.asInstanceOf[Double].doubleValue()
        val mchc: Double = entity.attrs("mchc").value.asInstanceOf[Double].doubleValue()
        val mcv: Double = entity.attrs("mcv").value.asInstanceOf[Double].doubleValue()
        actorSysMsj.start((entity.id, gender,age,hemoglobin,mch,mchc,mcv),conf)
        (entity.id, gender,age,hemoglobin,mch,mchc,mcv)
      })
    processedDataStream.print
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
}
```

But when I trigger, the subscription fails showing the next (not only on 10.0.1.2 but 10.0.1.3 VM too):

```
{"id":"61cb8569a1e87a254e16066d",
"description":"Suscripcion de anemia para monitorear al Paciente",
"expires":"2040-01-01T14:00:00.000Z",
"status":"failed",
"subject":{"entities":[{"id":"Paciente1","type":"Paciente"}],
"condition":{"attrs":["calculateAnaemia"]}},
"notification":
{"timesSent":3,
"lastNotification":"2021-12-29T00:03:49.000Z",
"attrs":"gender","age","hemoglobin","mch","mchc","mcv"],"
onlyChangedAttrs":false,
"attrsFormat":"normalized",
http":{"url":"http://10.0.1.2:9002/notify"},
"lastFailure":"2021-12-29T00:03:54.000Z",
"lastFailureReason":"Timeout was reached"},
"throttling":10}]
```

The curious thing is when I worked with the subscription related to the 10.0.1.4 VM that has the CB container, the subscription remains active and i get my expected result.

This is the subscription:

```
 curl -v localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions -s -S -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- <<EOF
{
  "description": "Suscripcion de deceso para monitorear al Paciente",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "Paciente1",
        "type": "Paciente"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "calculateDeceased"
      ]
    },
    "expression":{
        "q":"calculateDeceased:1"
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://10.0.1.4:9004/notify"
    },
    "attrs": [
      "gender","age","hasAnaemia","creatinePP","hasDiabetes","ejecFrac","highBloodP","platelets","serumCreatinine","serumSodium","smoking","time"
    ]
  },
  "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z"
}
EOF
```

This is the answer when it is triggered and process perfectly:

```
{"id":"61caab07a1e87a254e160665",
"description":"Suscripcion de deceso para monitorear al Paciente",
"expires":"2040-01-01T14:00:00.000Z",
"status":"active",
"subject":{"entities":[{"id":"Paciente1","type":"Paciente"}],
"condition":{"attrs":["calculateDeceased"]}},
"notification":{"timesSent":1,"lastNotification":"2021-12-28T06:15:41.000Z",
"attrs":["gender","age","hasAnaemia","creatinePP","hasDiabetes","ejecFrac","highBloodP","platelets","serumCreatinine","serumSodium","smoking","time"],
"onlyChangedAttrs":false,
"attrsFormat":"normalized",
"http":{"url":"http://10.0.1.4:9004/notify"},
"lastSuccess":"2021-12-28T06:15:43.000Z",
"lastSuccessCode":200}}
```

I have to say I'm new to Spark, Scala and even Fiware. But projects are projects and maybe I'm missing something I did not see in all I read to set up this project. Also, I stopped all firewalls (firewalld) because I was facing a "Couldn't connect to server" error on subscriptions related to 10.0.1.2 and 10.0.1.3 VMs. I did an sudo yum update too, I pinged all the VMs between each other and I got nice response. One thing that I do not know if it is important: I have internet on all my VMs but I can't ping for example... [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or 8.8.8.8. So, any suggestions are welcome! I apologized for my english. Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 1):

Well, after 3 days of keep looking and trying i just discovered that I need to turn off the 1.2 and 1.3 firewalls and keep it on 1.4.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The only thing i did was turn off my firewalls on Centos7 (systemctl stop firewalld) from 10.0.1.2 and 10.0.13 machines. Just for the 10.0.1.4 the firewall must be active. After that my subscription works perfectly~